# Resume download using URLSessionDownloadTask when app relaunches

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

Trying to resume a download across app launches i.e if the user quits the app by swiping from the multi-tasking screen while downloading is in progress, then on app relaunch, the download should start from where it stopped in the previous run. To achieve this, I am calling a method from applicationDidEnterBackground. This methods cancels the running downloadTask using: cancel(byProducingResumeData: completionHandler) and then stores the resumeData object received. On app relaunch, I fetch the resumeData object, create a downloadTask with this resumeData and start the task by calling resume. But facing these issues with this approach:

1. Download is always starting from scratch. I tried converting resumeData to a dictionary, so that I can access the value for key - "NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath" and see if the file is available or update the path to check if that helps resume download. But unable to get the value of this key.

   let dict = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: PropertyListSerialization.ReadOptions(), format: nil) as? NSDictionary
   let array = dict!["$objects"] as? NSArray

Inside the above array, there is no value for key: NSURLSessionResumeInfoTempFileName. On printing, it looks like this:

```
- 4 : NSURLSessionDownloadURL
- 5 : NSURLSessionResumeInfoTempFileName
- 6 : NSURLSessionResumeBytesReceived
- 7 : NSURLSessionResumeInfoVersion
```

Is there any other way to fetch value of "NSURLSessionResumeInfoLocalPath"?

2. Apple documentation says, app will have about 5 seconds before it gets terminated, but that is not happening every time. Sometimes the application is getting terminated almost instantaneously, even before the method I am calling from applicationDidEnterBackground gets a chance to generate and save resumeData. Is there a way to avoid this and ensure that the method gets enough time to complete its run?